# How can I run Docker-based project without installing docker into my windows machine

Tags: docker, github, windows-installer

In order to test a Docker-based project from the GitHub, I'm obliged to install docker, I'm wondering if there some solutions to run it without installing docker into my windows 8.1 machine.

Comment: You can install Docker into a VM (this is what Docker Toolbox and Docker Machine do) but you fundamentally need Docker to run Docker-packaged software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either install docker OR configure local setup yourself.

EXAMPLE:
if the docker project is a web app, you will have to install webserver OR docker (you can have both installed) and chose if you want to run the code by using docker or your local webserver instance.

In such case docker is not required.